# O-ring compressive force

Tags: waterproofing, seals

Is there formula to calculate the compressive force required to achieve x% of squeeze in an O-ring? I have referred the Parker O-ring and Apple Rubber Handbooks, but they provide just approximations. I am trying to calculate the linear force per length for a 4 mm o-ring and I want to achieve 25% squeeze.

Comment: Temperature may also be a factor that you should consider.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, if you need more precision than what the handbooks tell you, your best bet is to buy some o-rings and test them under the range of conditions under which you expect them to function.

Comment: I am okay with the approximations but my trouble is that these handbooks do not have data for o-ring size close to 4 mm cross section. Nearest one is 0.139 inches, which is half a millimeter smaller than 4 mm. I don't know how or whether to approximate that. That's why I am looking for a formula.

Comment: Call the vendor supplying the 4mm o-rings and ask them for the data.